# Need help in fetch query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table of cocktails that contains Id and name of Cocktail (say id in range 1-16).
These cocktails will be made by any combination of different ingredients. Usually each cocktail made by 3 ingredients or more.

So I created a table Recipe that contains the details of each cocktail. For example cocktail with id 1 is made by ingredients' id - 1, 4, 14.

Now suppose I have only ingredients 1-7 (any random 7 ingredients).cI need to fetch all those cocktails that are created by ingredients that I have.

I tried following query, but it returns me all cocktails because each cocktail contains at least one of ingredient

```
SELECT * FROM SB_receipe WHERE ingr_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) GROUP BY cock_id;
```

Please help me to fix out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give us the structure of the tables.

Comment: Just use group and concat. Before doing it, order by ingredientID as C and your ingredient string is ASC too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a query that returns cocktails that use *only* ingredients you have.

SQL has no keyword `ONLY`; you have to express this with a double negation:
You want cocktails for which *no* ingredient exists that is *not* in your list:

```
SELECT *
FROM cock
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SB_recipe
                  WHERE cock_id = cock.id
                    AND ingr_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

Alternatively, you do *not* want any cocktails that use any ingredient that is *not* in your list:

```
SELECT *
FROM cock
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT cock_id
                 FROM SB_recipe
                 WHERE ingr_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```